# Arbitrary functions Synthetic Control Time series

Tags: time-series, causality, synthetic-cohort

I am aware that in synthetic control you create the synthetic control time series by effectively creating a weighted average of the matched/donor controls (plus extra covariates).

My question is, is it wrong to have an arbitrary function like a gradient boosted model for estimating the test time series in the preintervention period?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some disagreement on whether this is good or not.

Restricting the weights to [0,1] and forcing them to sum to one precludes extrapolation. The SC approach uses interpolation because the causal effect is always based on a comparison between the treated outcome and the convex hull of control group outcomes. This means the counterfactual is based on where the data actually is, as opposed to extrapolating beyond the support of the data, like a general ML method might do.

Here is [a paper](https://www.nber.org/papers/w22791) arguing that some extrapolation might be desirable (allowing for negative weights that don't sum to one).

Comment: (I have already upvoted this answer in the past) In general, I see the "*weights to [0,1] and forcing them to sum to 1*" as a way to indirectly regularised model complexity without explicitly saying it. There is no good reason why at least "mild extrapolation" cannot be fully reasonable; I appreciate that negative weights are always tricky to interpreter especially when people's first approach is to interpret the weights as mixing coefficients but the "sum to 1" is really like some past forecast reconciliation approaches who were trying to play it safe (and worked).